# How to change text on the TextView widget by using a Spinner dropdown

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I got a practical to do. I have to make a measurement converter android app using java. It involves using a spinner dropdown menu. [This link is the image of my practical handout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsSVS.jpg)  As shown in the image if the user selects miles to kilometers in the spinner dropdown menu, the TextView widgets would show miles and kilometers. However I am not able to get that working. I will provide you sample code now.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
TextView.OnEditorActionListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
private Spinner conversions;
private String list [];
private TextView u1;
private TextView u2;
private EditText input;
private TextView convertedUnit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    conversions = findViewById(R.id.converterSelector);
    u1 = findViewById(R.id.unit1Lbl);
    u2 = findViewById(R.id.unit2Lbl);
    input = findViewById(R.id.enterNum);
    convertedUnit = findViewById(R.id.convertedNumLbl);
    list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.conversion_types);



   // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.conversion_types, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
    conversions.setAdapter(adapter);

    conversions.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    u1.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
}


public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    String menuComponent = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

    if(menuComponent.equals(pos)){
        if(pos == 0) {
            u1.setText(getString(R.string.milesLbl));
            u2.setText(getString(R.string.km));


            double mile = (double) 
            Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(input.getText()));
            double kiloMeter = mile * 1.6093;
            convertedUnit.setText("" + kiloMeter);
        }


    }
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
}

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

}
}
```

My app crashes with this following code. Could you please find out what the problem is and if you find out the problem can you paste the correct code to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: please ad crash log. in the snippet

Answer (score 2):

OnItemSelected you can get the position and perform a method according to it.

```
 @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    switch (i){
        case 0: milesToKilo();
        break;
        case 1: kiloTomiles();
        break;
        case 2: inchesToCenti();
        break;
        case 3: centiToInches();
        break;
        default:
    }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}

public void milesToKilo(){
    u1.setText("Miles");
    u2.setText("Kilos");

    // rest of calculations

}
public void kiloTomiles(){

    u1.setText("Miles");
    u2.setText("Kilos");
    // rest of calculations

}

public void inchesToCenti(){
    u1.setText("inches");
    u2.setText("Centi");
    // rest of calculations

}
public void centiToInches(){
    u1.setText("Centi");
    u2.setText("Inches");
    // rest of calculations

}
```